# Custom Ribbon - Update editbox along with cell value

Tags: excel, xml, vba, ribbon

I have an edit box that pulls value for a certain cell.

However, it stays static.

I'd like the value to update when the value of the cell updates.

XML:

```
<editBox id="txt1" getText="GetText"  getEnabled="GetEnabled" />
```

VBA:

```vb
Sub GetText1(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef returnedVal)
    '***** Return the value in cell A1 in sheet #1 in the workbook that holds the code
    returnedVal = Range("DealMultiple")
End Sub

Sub GetEnabled(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef returnedVal)
    '***** Return wheter you want the editBox to be enabled or not
    returnedVal = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

When the value of the cell is changed you need to call the `Invalidate` method to get callbacks invoked anew. For example, if an add-in writer implements the `getImage` callback procedure for a button, the function is called once, the image loads, and then if the image needs to be updated, the cached image is used instead of recalling the procedure. This process remains in place until the add-in signals that the cached values are invalid by using the Invalidate method, at which time, the callback procedure is again called and the return response is cached. The add-in can then force an immediate update of the UI by calling the `Refresh` method.

```
Dim MyRibbon As IRibbonUI 
 
Sub MyAddInInitialize(Ribbon As IRibbonUI) 
 Set MyRibbon = Ribbon 
End Sub 
 
Sub myFunction() 
 MyRibbon.Invalidate() ' Invalidates the caches of all of this add-in's controls 
End Sub
```

In the `onLoad` callback you may retrieve the `IRibbonUI` instance.

Read more about the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)